# How to use HTTPGet variable in URL (ExactTarget)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, formatting, http

Been trying to figure out a way to pass in the variable into a `HTTPGet` function for long time now.  How to do it?  Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't return anything.

```
<p id="date" style="font-family:Georgia, serif; color:#446c5a; font-style:italic; font-size:16px; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:0;">%%xtmonth%% %%xtday%%, %%xtyear%%</p>

%%[Var @curdate, @url

SET @curdate = Format(Now(), "MMddyyyy")
SET @url = Concat("http://theurltograbdatafrom.com/index.php?d=", @curdate)

HTTPGet(@url)
]%%

<p>%%=v(@url)=%%</p>
```

Have also tried the following:

```
<p id="date" style="font-family:Georgia, serif; color:#446c5a; font-style:italic; font-size:16px; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:0;">%%xtmonth%% %%xtday%%, %%xtyear%%</p>

%%[Var @curdate, @url
SET @curdate = Format(Now(), "MMddyyyy")
SET @url = Concat("http://theurltograbdatafrom.com/index.php?d=", @curdate)
httpget; @url ]%%

<p>%%=v(@url)=%%</p>
```

Both examples return absolutely nothing!  However the return value in `<p>%%=v(@url)=%%</p>` returns the proper URL, but how to use this url in either of these ways??

I am putting this code in a `Content Area` and than calling it from within an email that has that content retrieved into it.

Comment: Sorry, but how it is related to Salesforce?

Comment: Where is the exact target support forum?  I did a search on Exact Target Help and this came up as #1 on the list.

Comment: I would just ask this question in general stackexchange forum.

Comment: Can you update the question with references to where it applies in ExactTarget? I.e. in what context is the HttpGet being called. As it stands it doesn't look like a Salesforce related question. ExactTarget questions are fine, but you might need to be more specific.

Comment: @Chiz - If you go here:  https://code.exacttarget.com/questions it says to go to this site and ask the question (at the very top of the page)!  Cheers :)

Comment: ExactTarget hasn't always been a heavy topic in this exchange.  That is more of a recent thing.  Most of us are unfamiliar with the formatting you were using.  When you're asking for help on ExactTarget make sure to be very clear that is what you're looking for help on since ExactTarget isn't part of the core platform (yet).  A tag for ExactTarget would be helpful to add as well.

Comment: @DanielBallinger - It's being called in a Content Area.  And a tag for Exact Target does exist.

Comment: @Solomon Closson - wow :-) OK. But nevertheless, I would suggest you to post this question in http://stackoverflow.com/ I think people from there will answer your question faster then we. Although, I'm surprised of number of votes for your question O_o I'll give you my vote too :-)

Comment: @Chiz - I disagree with you.  ExactTarget is a Salesforce platform and it is slowly being integrated into the marketing cloud.  Might as well build up all of the knowledge around it now.

Comment: All I know is that the Exact Target Answer and Question section says to go to this site for questions on Exact Target and post it up as a Tag with Exact Target in the tag.

Comment: @drakored now I see. Salesforce bought ExactTarget. And it's marketing stuff. It's just I don't deal with marketing stuff at all, that is why it was confusing for me how it's related to Salesforce. Sorry, no more comments on this.

Comment: Hopefully an educated answer on this is sure to come soon?  Thanks for your comments all!

Comment: @SolomonClosson - I don't know Exact Target but making an educated guess from their documentation, try ending your block after you declare the url var, then below that do this:  %%httpget @url%%

Comment: When I do that I get this error `An exception occurred when attempting to retrieve content by a HttpGet call. URL: @url
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

Comment: Last comment on the topic but just for future reference we had a bit of a discussion on meta around whether ET questions would 'fit' this site and the overall consensus was that they definitely would, so while the technologies don't have a lot of crossover right now ET questions are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here ya go for everyone needing to know this.  Here's how it is done:

```
<p id="date" style="font-family:Georgia, serif; color:#446c5a; font-style:italic; font-size:16px; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:0;">%%xtmonth%% %%xtday%%, %%xtyear%%</p>

%%[Var @curdate, @url
SET @curdate = Format(Now(), "MMddyyyy")
SET @url = Concat("http://theurltograbdatafrom.com/index.php?d=", @curdate) ]%%

%%=HTTPGet(v(@url))=%%
```

Many Thanks go to drakored for the syntax help on this!

Comment: Ha, no problem.  I was just about to post something similar for you to try out.  Interesting syntax they have.  This page should be helpful to anyone trying to learn this:  http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/

Comment: I'm so happy that this is now working!  I can relax now!  I'm wondering if `dd` in the format string though will return `05` on the 5th day or if it just returns `5`.  I need to return `05`, should it be changed to `DD` instead for this?

Comment: The docs I read said it's C# based.  This page seems to indicate you'd be fine with dd as long as that page I read was correct that this is C# based.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: From ExactTarget docs:  "S1    A C# compatible format string. Valid values include:"

Comment: Yeah, I tried with `DD` and that just put the letter in there.  So guess I will be using `dd` instead, as my original way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to this answer.  If you want to track links from the html you are pulling in, you will need to use a wrap function as well, as so:

```
%%[
set @var1 = "http://someurl.com"

var @getStatus, @content, @content2
set @content = HttpGET(treatascontent(@var1), false, 2, @getStatus)

set @content2 = Replace(treatascontentarea('TEST',@content),'http','httpgetwrap|http')

]%%

%%=TreatAsContent(@content2)=%%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the RedirectTo function to use the URL inside your html code.

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@linkURL)=%%" target="_blank">
```

Comment: While this is great and all, this is a URL only.  I needed to pull in an entire webpage based on a dynamic URL as content inside of the email.  This is much different than pulling in the url into an email.  But thanks for the addition to this just the same.